# Is there a Encoding in SQL Server integration Services which encodes charter values

Tags: encoding, ssis

I have a SQL Server and a database (SERVER A : Database D1) and I am transferring some data to a different server (SERVER B : Database D2) using select Stored procedures(From the Source) and Insert Stored procedures(at destination). There is one VARCHAR type data which transferred from source to destination and there is a text eg. (+/-75) which is getting converted to (+/?75) after the data transfer.

I am not making any special changes in my SP's to convert "-" to "?". Is there a configuration or encoding which is causing this issue .?

Does anyone faced this issue with SSIS packages.

FYI, - I have transferred the data within the same server to a different database and the charters were transferred fine without any issues.

Checked the SP's and could not find any explicit conversion or data processing in SSIS.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by (+/-75) vs (+/?75). Can you please explain more. Any screenshots or error messages might be helpful.

Comment: There is no error messages, this SSIS package is transferring data from one database to another (both are in different server ) the source data is : "+/-75". When it is inserted in destination it is getting changed to "+/?75".

Comment: I see - it is odd that SSIS is transforming the data value. Is this a one-time transfer or is this something that needs to be done more than once? If it is a one-time transfer, you might be better of just using the SQL Server 201X Import Data utility. If you need to use the sprocs then you might need to post the code. Have you tried setting the source and destination to NVARCHAR()?

Comment: What is the `Fulltext language LCID` of the database instance and database for both A and B?